# Stop emacs erc from recentering

Tags: emacs

Emacs erc keep recentering. It is very hard to keep up with the conversations in a small buffer because of it.

I've tried the followings but none seems to work...

```lisp
(erc-scrolltobottom-mode)

(require 'erc-goodies)

(setq erc-input-line-position -1)
(erc-add-scroll-to-bottom)

(add-hook 'erc-mode-hook 'erc-add-scroll-to-bottom)
(add-hook 'erc-insert-post-hook 'erc-scroll-to-bottom)
```

Is there a way to keep erc from recentering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Emacs (and not `erc`) tries to recenter the screen every time, the cursor moves out of visible portion. See the docstring of `scroll-conservatively`(<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`scroll-conservatively`<kbd>RET</kbd>)

> Scroll up to this many lines, to bring point back on screen. If point
>   moves off-screen, redisplay will scroll by up to
>   `scroll-conservatively' lines in order to bring point just barely onto
>   the screen again.  If that cannot be done, then redisplay recenters
>   point as usual.
>
> If the value is greater than 100, redisplay will never recenter point,
>   but will always scroll just enough text to bring point into view, even
>   if you move far away.
>
> A value of zero means always recenter point if it moves off screen.

So setting `scroll-conservatively` in `erc-mode-hook` might do the trick

```
(add-to-list 'erc-mode-hook (lambda ()
                              (set (make-local-variable 'scroll-conservatively) 100)))
```

Actually there are a lot of ways to achieve what you want. Have a look at [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Scrolling.html) of the Emacs manual

Comment: I've spent alot of time trying to figure out how to fix it and your solution did it, thanks alot (really alot). I've also added `(require 'erc-goodies)` before.

Comment: I am really glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION # 1**:  Comment out line 101 of the Github source code in the following link -- i.e., comment out the line of code that looks like this:  `(recenter (or erc-input-line-position -1))`

https://github.com/emacsmirror/erc/blob/master/erc-goodies.el

```lisp
(defun erc-scroll-to-bottom (window display-start)
  "Recenter WINDOW so that `point' is on the last line.

This is added to `window-scroll-functions' by `erc-add-scroll-to-bottom'.

You can control which line is recentered to by customizing the
variable `erc-input-line-position'.

DISPLAY-START is ignored."
  (if (window-live-p window)
      ;; Temporarily bind resize-mini-windows to nil so that users who have it
      ;; set to a non-nil value will not suffer from premature minibuffer
      ;; shrinkage due to the below recenter call. I have no idea why this
      ;; works, but it solves the problem, and has no negative side effects.
      ;; (Fran Litterio, 2003/01/07)
      (let ((resize-mini-windows nil))
        (erc-with-selected-window window
          (save-restriction
            (widen)
            (when (and erc-insert-marker
                       ;; we're editing a line. Scroll.
                       (> (point) erc-insert-marker))
              (save-excursion
                (goto-char (point-max))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; LINE 101 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                ;; (recenter (or erc-input-line-position -1))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                (sit-for 0))))))))
```

---

**SOLUTION # 2**:  In your `.emacs` file, you can create a new function and a `defalias` like this:

```lisp
(require 'erc-goodies)

(erc-scrolltobottom-mode)

(setq erc-input-line-position -1)

(erc-add-scroll-to-bottom)

(add-hook 'erc-mode-hook 'erc-add-scroll-to-bottom)

(add-hook 'erc-insert-post-hook 'erc-scroll-to-bottom)

(defun guimobob-erc-scroll-to-bottom (window display-start)
  "Recenter WINDOW so that `point' is on the last line.

This is added to `window-scroll-functions' by `erc-add-scroll-to-bottom'.

You can control which line is recentered to by customizing the
variable `erc-input-line-position'.

DISPLAY-START is ignored."
  (if (window-live-p window)
      ;; Temporarily bind resize-mini-windows to nil so that users who have it
      ;; set to a non-nil value will not suffer from premature minibuffer
      ;; shrinkage due to the below recenter call. I have no idea why this
      ;; works, but it solves the problem, and has no negative side effects.
      ;; (Fran Litterio, 2003/01/07)
      (let ((resize-mini-windows nil))
        (erc-with-selected-window window
          (save-restriction
            (widen)
            (when (and erc-insert-marker
                       ;; we're editing a line. Scroll.
                       (> (point) erc-insert-marker))
              (save-excursion
                (goto-char (point-max))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                ;; (recenter (or erc-input-line-position -1))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                (sit-for 0))))))))

(defalias 'erc-scroll-to-bottom 'guimobob-erc-scroll-to-bottom)
```

Comment: I have modified the file given by (locate-library "erc-goodies"), but it doesn't seems to change anything...

Comment: The file that needs to be modified is `erc-goodies.el`.  You should delete `erc-goodies.elc` and `erc-goodies.gz`.  Then, with the modified `erc-goodies.el`, run `M-x byte-compile-file`.  Then **restart** Emacs.  On a few occasions on OSX 10.6.8, I have had to throw out my trash because Emacs was still accessing it for some reason.  Since you are commenting out the **only** `recenter` command in the entire library, there is no reason why it shouldn't work.  If you want, you can re-compress `erc-goodies.el` into `erc-goodies.gz` and then delete `erc-goodies.el` -- however, that is **optional**.

Comment: Just to make sure that we are on the same wave-length, you are commenting out the line of code that looks like this:   `(recenter (or erc-input-line-position -1))`  When you comment out code, you do it by placing `;;` to the left of the line being commented out.  When you are done, the line of code will look like this:  `;; (recenter (or erc-input-line-position -1))`  When I referred to **line 101**, that is the line number in the Github source code in the link of my answer.

Comment: Another way to accomplish the same goal is to write a new function with a different name.  You can copy the function `erc-scroll-to-bottom` over to your `.emacs` file and call it `guimobob-erc-scroll-to-bottom` instead of `erc-scroll-to-bottom`.  Then, underneath it, you can put `(defalias 'erc-scroll-to-bottom 'guimobob-erc-scroll-to-bottom)` and **restart** Emacs.  `(require 'erc-goodies)` must be **above** the `defalias` line of code.  Of course, you still need to comment out `(recenter (or erc-input-line-position -1))`